# Change font name AND weight in UILabel (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, uilabel

Maybe I'm looking at the wrong place, however how do I set an UILabel's font and AND its weight?

Looking at the documentation, there seems to be only methods to create an UIFont with a given font name and size, like

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22])
```

OR create a bold font, with

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22]
```

How can I use these both together?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [documentation for fontWithName:size:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/fontWithName:size:) states, "...name incorporates both the font family and the specific style information for the font."

So you probably want:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:22];
```

[fontNamesForFamilyName:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/fontNamesForFamilyName:) is handy for getting a list of available fonts for a given family.

For example:

```
NSArray* fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica"];
for( NSString* aFontName in fontNames ) {
    NSLog( @"Font name: %@", aFontName );
}
```

...which outputs:

```
Font name: Helvetica-BoldOblique
Font name: Helvetica
Font name: Helvetica-Oblique
Font name: Helvetica-Bold
```

Comment: Excellent. I was trying the "global" family names, and didn't pay attention to the families of each font as well. Thanks.

Comment: That tip about fontNamesForFamilyName: was extremely useful. Didn't know that was there. Thanks!